# Assus EEE PAD Transformer emulator for eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

all

I am working on application which has some issues on Assus EEE Pad Transformer, So I need to test the on Assus EEE Pad Transformer emulator , but i searched alot i am not able to find  Assus EEE Pad Transformer emulator , please help how i can test the app for  Assus EEE Pad Transformer emulator.

Comment: You can't really emulate a certain device. The best you can do is set the same screen size,density,ram etc..